# Is there a way to remove xml header added by ElementTree.tostring method?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

Before writing processed data to xml I do some formatting so it would all look nice in the result xml document.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import xml.dom.minidom as mdom
(...)

for i in range(10):
    root = et.Element("main")
    (...)

    ugly_xml = et.tostring(root, 'utf-8', method='xml')
    parsed_xml = mdom.parseString(ugly_xml)
    nice_xml = parsed_xml.toprettyxml(indent=" " * 3)
    with open('test.xml', 'a') as f:
         f.write(nice_xml)
```

However the result file obviously has duplicate xml headers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
(...)
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
(...)
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Is there a way not to print xml header with tostring method? The docs didn't provide any info except that I can just try different types like 'html' or 'text'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pretty it up, the ElementTree author suggests the following [function](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint) to inject whitespace into the document (Example added):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i

m = et.Element(u'main')
s1 = et.SubElement(m,u'sub1')
s2 = et.SubElement(s1,u'sub2')
s2.text = u'马克'

print et.tostring(m,'utf-8')
indent(m)
print et.tostring(m,'utf-8')
```

Output:

```
<main><sub1><sub2>马克</sub2></sub1></main>
<main>
  <sub1>
    <sub2>马克</sub2>
  </sub1>
</main>
```

Note that `et.tostring` itself wasn't adding the header.

Comment: I am afraid it will impact the performance since I need to process a huge file. Running this function per every iteration could be costly.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need the 'utf8' encoding?  If so try:

```
"".join(ET.tostringlist(m, encoding='utf8', method='xml')[1:]))
```

But this may rely on `tostringlist` behaving in a non-standardized way...

Answer (score 1):

Use method "html"

Method is either "xml", "html" or "text" (default is "xml").

`et.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method="html").decode()`

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
>>> root = et.Element("main")
>>> et.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method="html").decode()
'<main></main>'
>>> et.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode()
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>\n<main />"
```

Comment: Great answer for the generic use-case where the header is causing problems.